# Why is Symfony missing dev bundles in prod environment?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

My Symfony application has a few dependencies that are only required for development, testing and the like. These are defined in my `composer.json` in the `require-dev` section.

Here is how I add them in `AppKernel.php`:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            // ...
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\LiipFunctionalTestBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }
}
```

When I update my application, I run `php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`. This installs all requirements not required for the dev environment and then clears the cache.

However, clearing the cache fails with the following message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle' not found in /my/project/app/AppKernel.php on line 29
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

This is not only a problem with the Doctrine Fixtures Bundle. If I change the order so the Liip Functional Test Bundle comes first then the error will be about that bundle.

Why am I seeing this error? Why does Symfony try to access these bundles even though we are explicitly not in the dev environment (notice the `--no-dev` composer flag)? And what can I do to make this go away without having to install all dev dependencies on the production machine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is because symfony default env is `dev`, `composer --no-dev` only tells composer not to install dev requirements, symfony does not know about the environment.
Use `SYMFONY_ENV=prod` environmental variable.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#c-install-update-your-vendors

E.g:
`$ SYMFONY_ENV=prod php composer.phar install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`

Comment: Nice! Knowing this small option is going help keep my production build process simple and clean.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell the the `cache:clear` command to run in a production environment.

```
php app/console --env=production cache:clear
```

(If necessary, changing "production" to whatever you're calling the particular non-dev environment you're dealing with)

Comment: Thanks, that is the core of the issue. Unfortunately, there is no way to add a command line parameter to the composer call that is then passed to the cache:clear command. Seems it must be done as Fracsi suggested.