# Symfony pass -env parameter when I run composer commands

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.3, docker-entrypoint

When I create a docker entrypoint script for my project I run:

```
php /bin/composer install --no-dev
```

But thhat throws an exception that is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "AjglBreakpointTwigExtensionBundle" from namespace "Ajgl\Twig\Extension\SymfonyBundle".

The code over the `AppKernel.php` that initializes the bundle is:

```
public function registerBundles()
 {
        //Other Bundle initialization
        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Ajgl\Twig\Extension\SymfonyBundle\AjglBreakpointTwigExtensionBundle();

       }

       return $bundles;
 }
```

This bundle I use int on `dev` and `test` environments where it has use. The container I build is for production use.

Therefore I want somehow to let the ScriptHandlers that when composer executes, theese run over a `prod` environment and not a `dev` one in order to supress the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298724/why-is-symfony-missing-dev-bundles-in-prod-environment) issue.

Just set the `SYMFONY_ENV` var to `prod` and use `composer install` then: 
`SYMFONY_ENV=prod php /bin/composer install --no-dev`

Comment: No is not duplicate because the whole point is how to supress a Symfony - related error. Even the answer is not the same. or close to solve the problem in the link you provided